# Django - 'AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response' on DRF endpoint with Middleware

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I wanted to create Middleware to add authentication to every endpoint automatically. It seems to be creating issues for Django Rest Framework endpoints using `@api_view` decorator. Whenever I run my unit tests for the below endpoint I get `AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response.` How do I fix this so that my middlware works on both APIView classes and endpoints with `@api_view` decorator?

View.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@swagger_auto_schema(
    operation_description="Get <count> most recent posts by category"
)
def get_most_recent_posts_by_category(request, category, count):
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Middleware

```
from datetime import datetime

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

from cheers.core.api.jwt_helpers import decode_cognito_jwt


class CognitoMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        auth = request.headers.get("Authorization", None)
        if not auth:
            return Response(dict(error='Authorization header expected'), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        parts = auth.split()

        if parts[0].lower() != "bearer":
            return Response(dict(error='Authorization header must start with bearer'),
                            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        elif len(parts) == 1:
            return Response(dict(error='Token not found'), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        elif len(parts) > 2:
            return Response(dict(error='Authorization header must be Bearer token'),
                            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        token = parts[1]
        try:
            res = decode_cognito_jwt(token)
            expiration = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(res['exp'])
            current_utc = datetime.utcnow()

            if current_utc > expiration:
                return Response(dict(error=f'current time:{current_utc} is after expiration:{expiration}',
                                     user_msg='Please login again'), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        except Exception:
            # Fail if invalid
            return Response(dict(error="Invalid JWT"),
                            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)  # Or HttpResponseForbidden()
        else:
            # Proceed with the view if valid
            return None
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'cheers.middleware.CognitoMiddleware.CognitoMiddleware'
]
```

Comment: In this case you might want want to consider just using `HttpResponse` instead of `DRF`'s `Response` when you return a response from your middleware. This is because `@api_view` handles the processing for `.accepted_renderer`, which is being bypassed by the middleware causing errors

Comment: @BrianD how do you fix this then? Also why should I use `HttpResponse` over DRF's `Response`?